# Philosophical foundations for the choice of quantum operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

My current understanding is that a quantum system can be in a superposition of possible outcome states that are eigenstates of a particular operator on the wavefunction. However, it is also my understanding that these operators are essentially chosen based on brute experimental fact. If we always observed the particle appear in three locations, then we would use a different operator to account for this fact. My question is about the philosophical implications around which operators work...and what the particle "is" before measurement. It seems that interpretations of quantum mechanics are more concerned with the measurement problem, and less concerned with the nature of the particles themselves.

Can anyone point me toward investigations of this kind? I suppose you've got to just say "that's how things are" at some point, but I am wondering whether people have thought about this.

Comment: Side remark: a particle in a state that is a superposition of three position eigenstates would not appear to be in three locations at once, it would be precisely in a superposition of three locations. "A particle" appearing in three locations at once would rather be three particles, each in a particular position eigenstate.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Yes, but I was not saying that the particle was in a superposition of three eigenstates. I was inventing a new universe in which the particle being in three locations was a single eigenstate.

Comment: A particle being in three locations cannot be a single eigenstate because I don't know what it means. What could be a single eigenstate (of some operator) is the state which is a superposition of three position eigenstate. I can write down what it would look like, for example, it could read $\vert x_1\rangle+\vert x_2\rangle +\vert x_3\rangle$ (forgetting normalization, etc. because, of course). Can you write down what you are proposing would look like?

Comment: Again, three particles being in three locations could be an eigenstate. It would read $\vert x_1\rangle \otimes \vert x_2\rangle \otimes \vert x_3\rangle$. In fact, it is an eigenstate of the position operator $X_1\otimes X_2\otimes X_3$ on the Hilbert space obtained by taking outer product of three distinguishable particles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physically useful/interesting/relevant operators are the ones who are generators of certain physical symmetries. For example, the momentum operator is the generator of translations in space, the Hamiltonian is the generator of translations in time, the angular momenta/spin operators are the generators of rotations in space, etc. Such operators are useful/interesting/relevant because if the system possesses the relevant symmetry then the quantities represented by the respective operators are conserved.

There is something extra (and quite hand-wavy) to be said about the position operator in particular. If there were to be a candidate position operator such that the usual objects would appear to be in a superposition of its distant eigenstates, I agree with you that we would not call it a position operator. In some basic sense, the reasoning is that we require the position operator to be such that the Hamiltonian is local in its eigenspectrum, i.e., interactions are local in its eigenspectrum. This, via decoherence, leads to classical objects being well-localized in the position basis.

Comment: Ahhhh so there *is* a more fundamental reason that these are the chosen operators.

Comment: I assume this is connected to Noether's Theorem, but do you know of a way to get an intuition for how the operators are connected to symmetries?

Comment: @JeffBass That the operators are generators of certain symmetries doesn't have much to do with Noether's theorem, it is just a matter of definition. It is more like whatever the generator of translations in space is is called momentum. But, yes, that they are conserved has to do with Noether's theorem and no, I don't have a good pre-mathematical intuition for it. Also, we call certain generators of symmetry by special names and remember them, etc. is because they are conserved -- so in that sense, all of it has to do with Noether's theorem.

Comment: So maybe just to back up one step. I'm not sure I understand your point about the position operator. Can you elaborate on why the particle being in two distant locations at once is not a valid eigenstate?

Comment: @JeffBass Because, as I said, I don't know what it means. How would you write it down? If you write down $\vert x_1 \rangle + \vert x_2\rangle$ then it is just a superposition of two position eigenstates -- which can, of course, be an eigenstate of some other operator but it is not "a particle being in two positions at once".

Comment: Sure, but can't we imagine a world where an eigenstate of "position" is composed of two locations like |x1, x2⟩? It would be a strange world, where every particle is always found in two places, but is it possible? I'm curious about the symmetry that lets us say that a particle will always be found in just one location.

Comment: @JeffBass I am not sure what it means. You didn't write down what would be such an eigenstate in terms of bras/kets. (You did write down a ket but it is just labeled by what you want it to be labeled. In usual notation $\vert x_1,x_2\rangle$ means $\vert x_2\rangle \otimes \vert x_2\rangle$ with appropriate Bosonic/Fermionic symmetrization which is two particles in two locations, not one particle in two locations.)

Comment: I'm just saying that instead of thinking of the wavefunction as a superposition of individual position eigenstates, what if it were a superposition of pairs of locations (which I know is not our world, I'm just using it as a thought experiment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122547/discussion-between-dvij-d-c-and-jeff-bass).

Comment: Could you potentially just go a bit more into why objects end up appearing localized? I'm not sure I'm prepared to understand the implications of "the Hamiltonian is local in its eigenspectrum". Is this all mathematics that is added later in order to account for the fact that we always observe a particle at one location, or is there a deeper reason we believe this should be the case?

Comment: @JeffBass By Hamiltonian being local in the eigenspectrum of the position operator, I mean that interactions are local in space as I mentioned in the answer. In other words, it means that causes propagate locally in space. We expect this to be the case for various reasons. One can say that this is due to relativity. But, even more fundamentally, this is crucial as a basis of science. If causes were to propagate non-locally in space then there would be no way to design an isolated experiment and conclude something about a particular phenomenon without worrying about the whole of the universe.

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by "mathematics that is added later to account for the fact that we observe a particle at one location". As I mentioned earlier, simply from quantum mechanics, we would expect decoherence to happen in the basis in which the Hamiltonian is local -- and thus, we would predict that the classical world would look localized in the basis in which the Hamiltonian is local. We just call this basis the position basis because we already have the name "position" for the basis in which things are localized.

Comment: I guess the deeper question was why a single wavefunction couldn't interact with a detector screen in more than one location (and then interact locally in each separate location). It seems like the explanation is simply that our definition of "a particle" is "a little point-like thing that hits one location on a detector". That's satisfying enough as far as the physics is concerned, but doesn't explain what a particle really *is*, but that's a question for the philosophy SE.